# Cannot get WFS features from GeoServer using OpenLayers 3

Tags: vector, openlayers, openlayers-2, vector-layer

I read a book about OpenLayers 3 and I guess its about an older OpenLayers version because it mentions a `ol.source.ServerVector` vector source for getting WFS layers from a server.

In the latest OpenLayers 3.9.0 that I use, when I search the [API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) the only vector sources I can find are [vector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html), [cluster](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html), [tileVector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.TileVector.html) and [imageVector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.ImageVector.html).

So my first question is, is `ol.source.ServerVector` deprecated? Should I use plain `ol.source.Vector` instead to fetch WFS features from my GeoServer service?

When I search "WFS" on the [OL examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/?q=wfs) I get only one [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=wfs) that uses `ol.source.Vector` to get WFS from GeoServer.

My second question is about the settings.

I don't get what this does `url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {`, how the URL is implemented and what the `strategy` exactly does. Can somebody explain or provide links to tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question ol.source.ServerVector is deprecated and yes you may use ol.source.Vector instead.
For you second question, you may read some info about the `url` here [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html). I use the `loader` function instead of url so I am not familiar to explain more about the `url`.

Now about the `startegy`. This is indicating which features to load. This could be:

1. `ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` means will only load features exist within you current map MBR.
2. `ol.loadingstrategy.all` means all features will be loaded in a single request
3. `ol.loadingstrategy.tile` means loading features based on a tile grid.

(you may find some info for strategies [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html))

This is an example of a wfs layer that may give you some idea (I am using the `loader` function)

```
var vecLyr = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
          var urlTo = CONTEXT_ROOT + '/proxygetfeatures?targetURL='+MainApp.getGSUrl()+'/wfs?request=GetFeature' +
                encodeURIComponent('&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&TYPENAME=sdo_test:LAYERNAME') +
                encodeURIComponent('&outputFormat=json')+
                encodeURIComponent('&srsname=EPSG:2100&BBOX=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:2100');

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url     : urlTo,
                method  : 'GET',  
                success: function(response) {
                    var res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                    });
                    vecLyr.getSource().addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(res,{
                       dataProjection : 'EPSG:2100',
                       featureProjection : 'EPSG:'+MainApp.Map.globalEpsgCode
                    }));

                }
            });
          },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        }),
        minResolution   : getResolutionFromScale(100,'min'),
        maxResolution   : getResolutionFromScale(30000,'max'),
        visible         : false,
        style           : Layers.Styler.ParseJsonSldToOlStyle(wfsSldDocs[0])
    })
```

Comment: I guess `loader` and `url` do the same job, but `url` has less options, just loads the data without leaving any room for manipulating them first. Nice answer

Comment: Wait. What is `Ext.Ajax.`? Why dont you just do `$.ajax(url, {type: 'GET'}).done(....).fail(....);` Thanks

Comment: I am just using extjs and not jquery. (its a piece of code on a project I am working on).don't bother  use $.ajax

Comment: Οκ φίλε. (Hope I got it, I guess you are Greek, I am too) Thanks for the help

Comment: greeks are everywhere. :))))).Try it but  If you want a sample with jquery aks me.